# Using xml and sqlite

Tags: xml, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xml or Sqlite, When to drop Xml for a Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77726/xml-or-sqlite-when-to-drop-xml-for-a-database)

Is there a point in using SQLite if I'm receiving data from a remote site in XML format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77726/xml-or-sqlite-when-to-drop-xml-for-a-database

Comment: I don't understand your question could you try to explain it with a bit more detail?

Comment: rethorical questions to ask before clarifying: In what context? What kind of data? What is it used for? The xml comes from a site - But where does it arrive? A handheld, desktop, or another site? None of the above?

Comment: Thanks jaroslav that link is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You get the data stored in a format designed for searching, and you get a query language to apply to it.