# Should I be using some sort of database?

Tags: php, database

In an attempt to redesign a website, I put [this page](http://casetheatre.com/photos_test.shtml) together by hand. However, there are currently over 100 more shows already that need to be added, and three new shows get added every year.

In the old system, a text document was used as a makeshift 'database'; it stored data about each show, with shows separated by '#' and data fields separated with ']'. Here's an excerpt:

```
#The Whorl of the Leaves]WhorlOfTheLeaves]3]F]167
#Aladdin]Aladdin]8]N]0
#A Christmas Carol]XmasCarol84-]7]N]0
#The Feral Child]FeralChild]7]N]118
#Camelot]Camelot]11]N]169
```

A PHP script was then used to extract the information about each show and make the page seen [here](http://casetheatre.com/previous_shows.php).

I'm sure a script could be used to put together a page such as the one shown above, but it seems like there should be a better system than a text document to store the information.

My question is: if the text document 'database' is working, should I bother changing it? Is there a better way to organize the information about each show?

Comment: Interesting choice of delimiters...

Comment: Yes. Yes yes yes, a thousand times yes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/77912/1063333

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) would be prefect for you. It's a tiny database that requires no configuration or setup - yet comes built into most PHP installs.

Just use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and your good.

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:/path/to/here/mydb.sq3');

$db->query('SELECT * FROM shows');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, there are a ton of "better" ways of doing this. But if you're happy with it and it works, why change it?

Answer (score -1):

You could save yourself a lot of trouble by using a content management system such as [drupal](http://drupal.org).

Comment: uh, if they are asking this question (no offense Fluffy) do you really think Drupal is the best solution?