# Which is better? Database or xmlfile?

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xml or Sqlite, When to drop Xml for a Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77726/xml-or-sqlite-when-to-drop-xml-for-a-database)

Today i had one question when i was creating android application. I use XML file to store data at client phone. I know about Sqlite ! But I prefer XML most because it makes easier to development ! So I am little bit confused between sqlite and XML ! Though I can use database ! But i had the question and I want answer what professionals prefer ?

Comment: Personally, if I'm reading and writing data for an app, I use a database. I use XML for readonly stuff and data transfer between systems. But, that's just me.

Comment: if the data is small then go with XML but for large amounts of data I'd say use the database.