# Android - Sqlite or Xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, healthvault

I am working on an android app that takes measures from an activity like

`date + time + int1 + int2 + int3 + string`.

I want to save those measures and then :

1) activity to show them in a list sorted by date + time and show only

```
 date + time + int1 + int 2
```

and when i click on to show all the fields in a new activity or a toast or a dialog

2) activity to be able to send the last day/ last 7 days / last 30 days records attached to an email

3) activity to draw 2-3 charts like pie chart/other using the records

4) i want to be able to send these records to Microsoft Healthsvault(it needs them at specific xml pattern)

Now i don't know how to go on.Should i use xml to save these records or sqlite.Which is better with what i want to do like charts etc
If i save them in a sqlite db can i easily export data to an xml file?or should i use only xml.It is convenient xml for the things i want to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a thread about the choice between SQLite and XML :

[Xml or Sqlite, When to drop Xml for a Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77726/xml-or-sqlite-when-to-drop-xml-for-a-database)

For your case, you want to store data, then extract them in a particular order : SQLite provides this functionnality natively...

Moreover, I think you can build an XML instance from a ResultSet easily (I don't know how to do it precisely, but I think it's not so hard).

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking into this myself a lot lately for my app and I think I've finally decided that SQLite is the way to go. It looks like xml is initially more straightforward but SQLite might be best for performance reasons. Or so I think.